# How can we disable VS 2010 Intellisense

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

My Visual Studio 2010 is too slow most of the time. So I decided to disable the vs2010 Intellisense. Can any one help me?

Comment: http://www.google.com.au/search?source=ig&hl=en&rlz=&q=disable%20visual%20studio%202010%20intellisense&meta=

Comment: [Ctrl + J.](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/zainnab/archive/2010/05/01/how-to-turn-off-automatic-intellisense-vstipedit0054.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft doesn’t provide any way to disable Intellisense. This wouldn’t be a problem, except Intellisense can and does crash.

To disable Intellisense, close Visual Studio and navigate to your vcpackages folder:

C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\VC\vcpackages

Rename the file feacp.dll to something like foulup.dll. Now Visual Studio won’t be able to load Intellisense, but rather than crash it will just quietly drop its features.

or

**Also have look to this solutions : [how to disable intellisense...](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/vcgeneral/thread/376d8d52-471a-4d8e-a7ef-f0f06959896d/)**

[Ctrl + J.](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/zainnab/archive/2010/05/01/how-to-turn-off-automatic-intellisense-vstipedit0054.aspx)

Comment: This feacp.dll rename worked in Visual Studio 2008 but not in Visul Studio 2010.

Comment: There's a way to disable Intellisense in VS2010. See my answer.

Comment: @lorancou - the question is asked 1 year before an its working for OP that what i know ...and it acceptance proove that ...

Comment: Sure but stating "Microsoft doesn’t provide any way to disable Intellisense." is misleading. There's an option in VS2010, why not using it?

Comment: @lorancou - agree but the see the date when question is asked....at the time it asked it works it point to not...i m not saying you are wrong...but rather than putting minus you edit the answer and include the option thats good practice...

Comment: Unfortunately all of these suggestions only work for the application development languages (C#, CPP, etc.).  Would be nice if there were some way to turn off all of the XML / XSD IntelliSense features -- or, better yet, turn off any validation or IntelliSense feature of your choosing.  Getting very tired of seeing hundreds of nonsense (more like "Well, duh!") schema "warnings"...

Answer (score 61):

For C/C++: Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> C/C++ -> Advanced -> Disable IntelliSense.

Update: This also works with VS2012.

Comment: But VS2010 still generates the enormous .sdf

Comment: Perfect for coding in MASM since VS doesn't recognize assembly.

Answer (score 1):

In case you are using ReSharper the way to disable IntelliSense is as following: ReSharper > Options... > Environment > IntelliSense > Autopopup > Enable Automatic IntelliSense Popup > Uncheck > Save > Profit.

This also works in Visual Studio 2012 for C#.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way I can think of: change the file extension association so that *.cs files open in a plaintext document window, not the C# editor.  Repeat for other extensions as desired.

Answer (score 0):

It's actually easy for most languages:

Select Tools/Options on the menu. On the Options dialog box, select Text Editor, then select the language you use, then select "General". Uncheck "Auto list members" and "Parameter completion".

Works on VS 2012, 2010, and others, and seems to be available for most languages including C#, Basic, and C/C++.

Answer (score 0):

1. Change the file extension to ".txt "
2. Edit without intellisense.
3. Change file extension back to what it was.