# Visual Studio on OS X under VMWare Fusion in "Unity" view

Tags: visual-studio-2010, macos, multiple-monitors, vmware-fusion

I'm developing using Visual Studio 2010, a MacBook Pro, VMWare Fusion, and Windows 7. When I put Fusion into Unity view, I get a strange and very annoying behavior from VS 2010: As I type, when an Intellisense window pops up, it steals the keyboard focus. Then I can't type any more until I press "escape" (often multiple times) to make the Intellisense windows go away. This generally happens several times while typing a single program line.

This problem does not occur in "Full Screen" view.

My reason for using Unity is to have Windows apps on multiple monitors.

Is there a way to get VMWare Fusion's Unity view to work with Visual Studio?

Comment: Is this a duplicate of this question over in SO?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12197771/no-syntax-highlighting-or-intellisense-for-c-sharp-files-in-vs-2012

Your second question about using multiple monitors with Unity in Fusion is completely separate from your first question, and probably should be in its own question.  If your IntelliSense question is a dupe of the one that I linked above, you could just edit your question to only have your multiple-monitor question.

Comment: Thanks for the replay and I always appreciate references to related tickets, but no, this question is different. In that situation, intellisense and highlighting weren't _happening_. For me they're happening, but repeatedly take keyboard focus away from the text I'm typing, forcing me to press escape key. Multi-monitors the reason I want to use the Unity view, which is where the problem occurs. I'll edit my question to try to make it less confusing. Thanks!

Comment: @nadyne, thanks for the help; I think the question is better now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer I've found is to disable intellisense.

Select Tools/Options on the menu. On the Options dialog box, select Text Editor, then select the language you use, then select "General". Uncheck "Auto list members" and "Parameter information".

This seems to work on all recent versions of Visual Studio including 2012.

More discussion is [here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5400939/how-can-we-disable-vs-2010-intellisense).